# Settings button in swift 3, Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, button, path, settings

The problem I have is that I want to have a settings button which when the user clicks it, takes them to a specified path in the settings such as sound settings. The only issue is that every method I've tried has been outdated for more recent versions of iOS 10. Does anyone have any suggestions for a method which I can use? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your app `Settings` page by...

```
let settings_app: URL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.shared.open(settings_app)
```

But you can't open other *Settings* app section from any app.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, I hope to help you

```
let settingsUrl = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) as! URL
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```